# Technical specs and features to look for in a good microphone/webcam

Tags: laptop, audio, microphone, webcam, chromebook

I am looking for help in selecting a webcam with good microphone for **low-volume voice** for Chromebook and Windows PC.
**What features and technical specs should I look for in such a webcam?**
**NOTE: I am not looking for shopping recommendations and products links, only for general, technical considerations.** (I asked for those in a [separate question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14022) on [hardwarerecs.SE](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com).)

Intended use: Zoom meetings.
**Audio: The person using it speaks in soft (low volume) voice, so the mic has to be able to transmit the sound well.**
Video: Average quality is acceptable (audio is much more important).
Computer: Chromebook (major use) and Dell Inspiron 5000 laptop running Windows 10 (minor use).

Possible technical specs to look for:

- Shielding against electromagnetic hum generated by computer monitors, neon lights, and other electrical devices.
- Frequency Response, such as 50-20,000 Hz.
- Cardioid polar pattern.
- Impedance: 150 ohms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These types of devices are really sold by price point.

They will all try to throw plenty of detail into their spec; some useful, some [intentionally] misleading. You'd need a degree in video & sound engineering to be able to spot the snake oil, so don't bother.

Pick a price point & divide it equally between webcam & a separate headset with built-in boom mic.

The upside of the headset mic is positioning. The closer you can get the mic to your mouth [without being directly in the airflow as you speak] the better your signal to noise ratio. From that close, speaking quietly will not disadvantage you.
The added benefit of this is you will get no feedback into your mic from the speakers you would otherwise be using, thus preventing irritating [to others] echo of their mic back into your transmission.

For a webcam, do you really need to be transmitting a full 4k picture to people over Zoom? … no, so don't bother. Look maybe for "FullHD", 1080p, but even that is higher detail than you absolutely need for what is essentially a phone call over the 'net. Unless you have to hold up detailed pictures to show people, a 720p camera is really sufficient.
Pretty much anything these days will have backlight compensation & auto-focus. Perhaps you might prefer one you can zoom via a control panel so your face better fits the screen. Anti-flicker [mains frequency compensation] is useful in artificial light. Don't let anyone sell you a feature you don't need, though.
These days many phone cameras have better lenses, sensors & automated features built-in than a cheap webcam will have. If you've a half-decent modern phone, look into webcam apps you can leverage into use - phone camera to Zoom, simply by connecting it to USB & maybe investing in a stand you can place the phone in.

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer is very useful to me: fact-filled, explanations are clear to a non-expert, and a lot of out-of-the-box thinking (headset mic vs webcam mic; phone camera, etc). I hope this thread does not get deleted and this answer will help other users in the future!